# Remove null values from SQL results

Tags: mysql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

The query below returns null rows in the output. We can avoid null rows if I've two separate queries. But is there a better approach to avoiding null rows?

```
SELECT date_part('h',convert_timezone('UTC+05:30',  value)) as h  ,  
       count (CASE WHEN cond1 THEN 1 else null END) AS "result1",
       count (CASE WHEN cond2 THEN 1 else null END) AS "result2"
FROM table_name
WHERE conds
GROUP BY cols

Expected Output:
h | result1 | result2

1 |   23    |   51
2 |   45    | 100

Actual Output:
h | result1 | result2

  |     0   |   0
  |     0   |   0                            
1 |   23    |   51
```

Comment: have you tried adding 'having h is not null '?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want another query, then try this approach:

```
SELECT date_part('h',convert_timezone('UTC+05:30',  value)) as h  ,  
count (CASE WHEN cond1 THEN 1 else null END) AS "result1",
count (CASE WHEN cond2 THEN 1 else null END) AS "result2"
FROM table_name
WHERE conds
GROUP BY cols
HAVING date_part('h',convert_timezone('UTC+05:30',  value)) is not null
```

In this example, you could alternatively expand your where conditions to include the same test for not null and forego using HAVING clause.